# How to insert command line arguments into bind command?

Tags: bash

Please consider the following file `inject.sh` with the following line:

```
#!/bin/bash
bind '"\e[0n": "echo test"'; printf '\e[5n'
```

When running `source inject.sh` it injects the text 'echo test' on a new line (not echo). This works correctly, as per one of the suggestions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213821

I want to replace the "echo test" part with all the command line arguments that might be provided to the script, so with `$@` basically. However I am having a hard time adding it into the command. I have tried with:

```
#!/bin/bash
bind '"\e[0n": "'$@'"'; printf '\e[5n'
```

But it only works if only one argument is passed to the command. So for example:

`source inject.sh ls` --> `bash-3.2$ ls|` OK (| is the cursor)
`source inject.sh echo foo` --> `bash-3.2$ echo|` NOT OK (does not print 'foo' and additionally it messes up the terminal, can't print some letters anymore)

Not sure where the problem is... Maybe wrong string concatenation?

Note this is a `bash` specific problem, not `zsh`, `fish` or something else. But for reference I am trying to emulate the `zsh` behavior of `print -z $@ echo foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
bind '"\e[0n": "'"$*"'"'; printf '\e[5n'
```

When you call `source inject.sh foo bar baz`, you want to concatenate them and put them in the same argument:

```
bind '"\e[0n": "foo bar baz"'
```

But you instead, you were splitting it across three invalid arguments:

```
bind '"\e[0n": "foo'    'bar'     'baz"'
```

Ways to debug this includes [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net), which spots both problems:

```
In inject.sh line 2:
bind '"\e[0n": "'$@'"'; printf '\e[5n'
                 ^-- SC2068: Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
                 ^-- SC2145: Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.
```

And `set -x` which shows how the command is being mangled:

```
++ bind '"\e[0n": "foo' bar 'baz"'    # Invalid attempt
++ bind '"\e[0n": "foo bar baz"'      # Valid command
```